# How to identify a hidden form field in Symfony2 / Twig

Tags: symfony, hidden, twig

I am new in Symfony2 and try to render a form. The basics are clear, but I have a problem with hidden form fields.

I try to render each form widget in a different table cell. But when using a for loop, the first cell is filled with the _token widget. But I like to render the hidden fields afterwards with form_rest.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    {% for element in form %}
      <td class="header">{{ form_widget(element) }} </td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I am looking for is something like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    {% for element in form %}
      {% if element.type != 'hidden' %} 
        <td class="header">{{ form_widget(element) }} </td>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below code

```
<table>
  <tr>
    {% for element in form %}
      {% if not element.ishidden %} 
        <td class="header">{{ form_widget(element) }} </td>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps you.
Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 5):

For Symfony 2.0 you used to do:

```
{% if "hidden" not in element.vars.types %}
```

For Symfony 2.1 you've got to do:

```
{% if "hidden" not in element.vars.block_prefixes %}
```

It took me ages to work this out because there is no documentation about it at all.  I'm also bemused as to why you can't just do:

```
{% if "hidden" element.vars.type %}
```

I mean, isn't this the most obvious way?

Comment: If you're using Sf2.1 (which is now the standard). This is the answer people should be looking for. Thanks Mike.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a shot in the dark, but maybe you can use the label in the if statement?

Sort of like {% if form_label(element) != "hidden" %}?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    {% for element in form %}
      {% if "hidden" not in element.vars.types %}
        <td class="header">{{ form_widget(element) }} </td>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</table>
```